# Apache mod_proxy_express and upgrade for WebSocket connections

Tags: apache, websocket, mod-proxy

I am using Apache as a reverse proxy to provide authentication in front of my apps. I'm using mod_proxy_express to dynamically manage how domain names are mapped to applications. The problem I am facing is that, when one of the apps tries to establish a WebSocket connection (through the Upgrade HTTP request), Apache does not allow it/proxy it to the app backend.

Reading [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#protoupgrade), how one usually enables this is by setting `upgrade=websocket` for ProxyPass directive. However, for mod_proxy_express I haven't found a way to set this (or any other ProxyPass parameter). Is there something I am missing here? Some other way to influence how mod_proxy_express proxies requests?